# Unit tests entity framework

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, юнит-тесты

Выдает такую ошибку Сообщение: 
Сбой Assert.IsNotNull.

Подключил ссылку на свой проект, пытаюсь проверить создает ли он в бд запись, как сделать так чтобы заработало?

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        ZOOPARK db = new ZOOPARK();
        Assert.IsNotNull(db.Staff.Where(user => user.Login_staff == "321" && user.Password_staff == "321").FirstOrDefault());
    }

    public void reg()
    {
        ZOOPARK db = new ZOOPARK();
        string log = "321";
        string passw = "321";
        string Name = "Вася";
        string Surname = "Пупкин";
        string Patronymic = "Алёшкин";
        string position = "Staff";
        Staff regs = new Staff
        {
            Name = Name,
            Surname = Surname,
            Patronymic = Patronymic,
            Position = position,
            Login_staff = log,
            Password_staff = passw,
        };
        db.Staff.Add(regs);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавил фотографию конфиг файла unit теста,

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, вы сказали про конфиг файл  и я заметил что там не было строки подключения, теперь можете подсказать каким методом проверять значения в базе данных ибо при использовании IsNotNull, вылетает ошибка Сообщение: 
Сбой Assert.IsNotNull.

Comment: я добавил данную строку в конфиг unit теста <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ZOOPARK" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Modelzoo.csdl|res://*/Modelzoo.ssdl|res://*/Modelzoo.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=KOMPUTER;initial catalog=ZOOPARK;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>

Comment: Я отредактировал, посмотрите!

Comment: Вообще, ваш первоначальный вопрос решён: путём добавления строки соединения в конфиг-файл. Это нужно было написать ответом, после чего принять его. И тема закрыта. / А по поводу ассёрта следовало задать новый вопрос. Так работает stackoverflow - конкретный вопрос - конкретный ответ. / Впредь делайте именно так. / Ну да ладно.

Comment: `db...Where(...).FirstOrDefault()` вернуло `null` - запись не найдена. / Вы метод `reg()` вызывали?

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с того, что `Assert` это просто статический класс с набором методов, которые брасают исключения в определённых ситуациях. `Assert.IsNotNull(object value)` это один из методов этого класса, который кидает исключение, если `value` является `null`. В этом вся суть тестового фреймворка: запустить код и "поставить галочку" напротив теста, если всё прошло гладко, без неожиданных исключений *****, или же "поставить крестик", если всё пошло иначе.

Рассмотрим ваш класс `UnitTest1`. В нём есть один тестовый метод: `TestMethod()`. Для того, чтобы было проще его анализировать, я его переписал в более читаемом виде:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var db = new ZOOPARK();
    
    var record = db
        .Staff
        .Where(user => user.Login_staff == "321" && user.Password_staff == "321")
        .FirstOrDefault();

    Assert.IsNotNull(record);
}
```

Итак, сначала инициализируется объект `db`, что то по-типу базы данных. После инициализации, я полагаю, она пуста.

```
var db = new ZOOPARK();
```

Затем происходит поиск первой записи, для которой выполняется определённое условие. Так как база данных пуста, это условие, я уверен, не выполнится и в результате вы получите `null`.

```
var record = db
    .Staff
    .Where(user => user.Login_staff == "321" && user.Password_staff == "321")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

После это вызывается метод `Assert.IsNotNull(record)`, который, очевидно, бросит исключение и тест будет **не** пройден.

```
Assert.IsNotNull(record);
```

Как я понимаю, вы ожидали, что тест будет пройден, так как у вас есть заполнение базы данных подходящими данными в методе `reg()`. Но вы не учли 2 момента:

1. Вы нигде не вызываете метод `reg()`
2. Метод `reg()` работает с локальной переменной `db`, зона видимости которой ограничена методом `reg()`

Есть 2 решения:

1. Перенести код заполнения `db` из метода `reg()` в метод `TestMethod()`
2. Вынести переменную `db` и сделать её полем класса `UnitTest1`, затем заменить инициализацию `db` в методе `TestMethod()` на вызов `reg()`

---

**для простоты понимания, я опустил то, что некоторые тесты наоборот могут ожидать выброса исключения ([ExpectedExceptionAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022))*